# Best way to approach large MySQL Database organisation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question relating to a general approach to a pretty large MySQL database. I've made some php code to interact with the database. I'm trying to analyse a hefty-ish set of data (~130k rows, 200 columns), and have been toying with different methods to do so. I've been learning a great deal along the way, and I feel as though I am close to getting it setup to be *really* speedy, but am still a bit stuck.

I began by being firmly in the 'excel' mindset. I continually added more and more columns to the dataset, as I was trying to select various bits and pieces out for the purpose of statistical analysis. Some of the php/mysql scripts I had made took hours.

Then, with at least the basics working, I learned about joins. This was a bit of a revelation I guess, but also resulted in me re-writing everything to get the joins to play nice with my data. The net result was a massive increase in performance - what took hours before takes about 15 seconds now.

After chatting with a few people, I came to the conclusion that I could still make it faster. The way I had it set up was so that different samples of data were each contained in a different table. Each table had it's data summarised in a further table that was used as part of the joins - general info about that particular dataset was stored in this secondary table for easy access and to increase speed.

Now, the question I have here is this: would it be better for me to change the way my database and application work so that all these different samples of data are combined into a single, large table? I've been experimenting with this so far for a bit, and it doesn't seem to be faster than the current method I am using.

In other words, is it better to run lots of 'little' queries involving multi-table joins, as I am doing at the moment, rather than a single, gigantic query involving multi-table joins? I've been examining the execution time of the queries and it seems like the joins are causing the slow-down for this new method.

I was under the impression that repeatedly sending small queries from PHP to MySQL was less optimal than just sending a single query, but is there a tipping point for more complex queries where this is not the case? Does it seem like I have reached that point?

Comment: Well it depends on what storage engine(s) youre using and how you have indexed the tables. There are two sides to the equation: 1. the actual schema youre using and 2. the each query you are issuing. Both can be optimized.

Comment: Ok, this is good to know. The main problem with these different samples of data is that there isn't an easy way to normalise them, as each row in them is entirely unique. At the moment, they are indexed with a unique row id (primary key) and a set of 3-4 index columns that are used as part of SELECT queries regularly. However, even UPDATEs at the moment seem to be taking a long time - with larger tables is it better to use a SELECT INTO instead to improve speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing query optimization in PHP is not the way to get the best performance out of the DB.  A properly formatted SQL query and MySQL's built-in query optimizer will probably do the job better.  (For example, the query optimizer in MySQL can do things like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_nested_loop)

But the real answer depends on what you're trying to do.  If speed is the number one priority, please list what you're trying to query and your data schema.  Answers will typically involve adding/removing indices and tweaking your queries.

If keeping your database footprint small is your goal (which I highly doubt given how cheap disk space is), normalize everything.

Comment: Ok, this is great to know - it's a bit messy at the moment, but generally speaking, is it the case that it's best to make sure to join on an indexed column with other indexed column(s)?

Comment: On huge tables where you're only interested in a subset of the data, this is generally a good practice.  But it all depends (sorry to be so unhelpful).  Database optimization is like a chess game.  For instance, keeping an index on a column isn't free.  Inserts will take longer to perform.  Lockup's can occur, etc. But on the flip side sometimes it's worth paying that cost.

Answer (score 1):

If your JOIN queries are done/indexed correctly, I would think they'd be better to use.

Comment: Ah, I figured as much - more that it was me not knowing what to do than anything else!